# How to write an xml file using libxml2 in python?

Tags: python, xml, libxml2

I am attempting to write an `xml` file in `python3` using `libxml2`. I cannot find any relevant documentation regarding `python` about writing files with `libxml`. When I attempt to write an `xml` file parsed with `libxml2` I get the error:

> xmlDoc has no attribute write

Anyone here done this before? I can get it to work in Etree just fine but Etree will not respect the attribute order that I need.

Comment: Are you able to use [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html)? It uses libxml2 (and libxslt). It's also easy to write to a file by using the write() method of the ElementTree object.

Comment: Sadly not :( It's an older linux system for work and I can't get lxml on to the system.

Comment: Please discuss your overall needs and not the specific tools. Python maintains [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) as part of its standard library and can easily develop XML files.

Comment: For my specific need and python version I needed a way to parse the xml files while respecting the attribute order, I am not able to download anything else nor perform a patch of etree, I'm basically limited to libxml2. I just cannot seem to write files parsed by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `saveFile()` or `saveFileEnc()`. Example:

```
import libxml2

XML = """
<root a="1" b="2">XYZ</root>
"""

doc = libxml2.parseDoc(XML)

doc.saveFile("test.xml")
doc.saveFileEnc("test2.xml", "UTF-8")
```

I could not find any good documentation for the Python API. Here is the corresponding C documentation: http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlSaveFile.

Answer (score 1):

```
import libxml2



DOC = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<verse>

  <attribution>Christopher Okibgo</attribution>

  <line>For he was a shrub among the poplars,</line>

  <line>Needing more roots</line>

  <line>More sap to grow to sunlight,</line>

  <line>Thirsting for sunlight</line>

</verse>

"""



doc = libxml2.parseDoc(DOC)

root = doc.children

print root
```

Comment: This does re-print the XML file, but how would you take this output and rewrite it as an actual .XML file in your path?

Comment: You can write file = open("filename.xml", "w+") then start writing in it using file.write()

Comment: That gives the same error I mentioned above, the 'xmlDoc object has no attribute 'write''.

Comment: Sorry I haven't really dealt with XML files but you can read this article that I found helpful for your situation https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python/  there are all examples you may look for using a module for it to work